# UIView-layer addAnimation:forKey:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation

Since the value of forKey is a NSString, where do I find a complete list of all possible value in the Apple documentation? Thanks

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question twice.  As one of the uninitiated, Apple's docs are NOT easy to search for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of animatable properties of CALayer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005942-SW1

and/or here

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005942-SW1

Comment: So is the string value that is supposed to be passed in to the forKey parameter the name of the animatable property for which you're adding an animation?

Comment: Good question. No it is not. The string value for this method is an arbitrary user-defined string associated with the animation. The `keyPath` property of a `CABasicAnimation` is the actual property to animate.

Answer (score 5):

The method `addAnimation:forKey:` doesn't do what you think it does.

The second string parameter is an arbitrary user-defined string to associate with the animation object. The purpose of this parameter is for accessing the animation object at a later time with the `animationForKey:` method.

The list of animatable properties provided above/below is pertinent to the `keyPath` property of a `CABasicAnimation` instance.